# DatePicker calendar too wide WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have the following datepicker:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="150" SelectedDate="{Binding Model.LoadingArrived, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
```

However, the calendar is too wide ([Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pr93.png)), more than necessary. How could I reduce its width?

[image]

Comment: looks like there is something wrong that you've not posted here. You should post more XAML code to get help on this.

Comment: You likely have a `<Style>` that indiscriminately targets all controls of a given type, such as `Border`, so any `Border` controls embedded within the DatePicker will also be affected. This is part of how XAML/WPF works compared to WinForms: Controls are not irreducible anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks King King, you were right.

I had this `<Style>` which was affecting the calendar:

```
<Grid.Resources>
     <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" TargetType="TextBlock">
          <Style.Setters>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
               <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
          </Style.Setters>
     </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

I commented it out and the `DatePicker` is being displayed properly now.

Thanks a lot.